# Behaviour of Simplify when used with ArcTan and ComplexExpand along with assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, core-language

I am trying to simplify the slope of vectors with symbolic coordinates {x,y} using ArcTan[x,y]
I am working with real X and Y

I tried the following :

```
ClearAll@L;
ArcTan[L, L]
ComplexExpand@ArcTan[L, L]
Assuming[Element[L, Reals] && L > 0, ComplexExpand@ArcTan[L, L]]
% // Simplify
Simplify[ComplexExpand@ArcTan[L, L], {Element[L, Reals], L > 0}]
```

and got the following output:

```
ArcTan[L, L]
Arg[(1 + I) L]
Arg[(1 + I) L]
Arg[(1 + I) L]
\[Pi]/4
```

Why is there a difference between the last line

```
Simplify[ComplexExpand@ArcTan[L, L], {Element[L, Reals], L > 0}]
```

and the third-last line?

```
Assuming[Element[L, Reals] && L > 0, ComplexExpand@ArcTan[L, L]]
```

Comment: The documentation states that *"Assuming affects the default assumptions for all functions that have an Assumptions option."*  Since `ComplexExpand` does not have an `Assumptions` option, it does not use the assumptions you specified in `Assuming`

Comment: Thanks you were right. On removing the assumption L>0 from the Simplify[] and the results match!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Assuming.html) states that:

> Assuming affects the default assumptions for all functions that have
>   an Assumptions option.

Since `ComplexExpand` does not have an `Assumptions` option, it does not use the assumptions you specified in `Assuming`.

Comment: Solved . . . . .